# JQ селекторы через data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я хочу сделать выборку

```
console.log($('[data-id=+name+]'));
```

Когда name равно слову "Круг" - JS находит его, а если в фразе будет пробел например "тестовый напиток", то JS дает ошибку:

> jquery.js:1468 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-id=тестовый напиток]

Подскажите, что делать в этом случае?

Comment: Погоди ты, нормальный вопрос, тут дело в другом

Answer (score 1):

Начал тестить
Вот этот код работает, он находит див, и с пробелами и без

```
$("body").append('<div data-attr="Кофе Чай"></div>');
$("[data-attr='Кофе Чай']").data('attr');
//И даже если так
name = 'Кофе Чай';
$("[data-attr='"+name+"']").data('attr');
```

Попробуй так:

```
console.log($('[data-id=+name+]')); //Твой код замени на
console.log($("[data-id='"+name+"']")); //Скорее всего дело в кавычках
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `.data()` для получения значения дата-класса

Пример:

```js
$("input[name=getValue]").on("click", function(){
  $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).data("id");
    if(val === "Круг")
      alert("val = Круг");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-id="Круг" value="круг"><br/>
<input type="text" data-id="Квадрат" value="квадратик"><br/>
<input type="text" data-id="Трегольник" value="трегольничек"><br/>
<input type="button" name="getValue" value="Получить все значения data-id" />
```